# Syntax Problems of if Statement (php)

Tags: php, syntax, if-statement

I need a little help with an if statement in php. I'm trying to set a variable called offset according to a page that I am loading in WordPress. Here's the variable:

```
$offset = ($paged * 6);
```

What it does is it loads the first page, which is:

http://example.com/blog

and $offset is thus set to 0 because $paged is referring to the appending number on the URL. The second page, for example is:

http://example.com/blog/2/

which makes $offset set to 12. The problem is, I need the second page to define $offset as 6, the third page to define $offset as 12, etc. I tried using:

```
$offset = ($paged * 6 - 6)
```

which works except on the first page. On the first page it defines $offset as -6. SO, I wanted to create an if statement that says if $paged is equal to 0 then $offset is equal to 0, else $offset is equal to ($paged * 6 - 6).

I struggle with syntax, even though I understand what needs to be done here. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because this is two different cases which cannot be easily integrated into a single formula, use an `if` statement:

```
if ($paged == 0)
  $offset = 0;
else
  $offset = ($paged - 1) * 6;
```

You can write this shorter using the [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary), but I think the above `if` statement is more readable:

```
$offset = ($paged == 0) ? 0 : ($paged - 1) * 6;
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative:

```
if($paged == 0) $paged = 1;
$offset = ($paged - 1) * 6;
```

or

```
$offset = ($paged) ? ($paged - 1) * 6 : 0;
```

Comment: Pages 0 and 1 will be the same... :D

Comment: @jadkik94 yep but what is the problem with that?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following one line code

```
$offset = max(($paged - 1) * 6, 0);
```

Comment: The `max()` solution, while clever, may be confusing for a future maintainer.

Comment: yes and no... it will also make him learn a simple trick. :-)

Comment: There's often a conflict between "simple tricks" and "maintainability". Otherwise everybody would be happy Perl coders.

Comment: you are absolutely right. I am actually big fan of tricks and smart coding. Thats why I oftenly use ternary operator wherever I can. Some may prefer to use if-else instead of ternary.

Answer (score 0):

You could use: `$offset = max(0, $paged * 6 -6);`. Which takes the maximum of 0 and the other value. If the other value is negative, then 0 will be the result.

Now, to use an if statement, this is how you would do it:

```
$offset = $paged * 6 - 6;
if ($offset < 0) {
    $offset = 0;
}
```

Or:

```
if ($paged == 0) {
    $offset = 0;
} else {
    $offset = $paged * 6 - 6;
}
```

And you might want to use a ternary operator for this simple case:

```
$offset = ($paged == 0)? 0: ($paged * 6 - 6);
```

(which does the exact same thing as the above)

Note: You could replace 6*a-6 = 6*(a-1), but it's of no importance in the code, just readability...